# Changing Excel input sheet each iteration (matlab)

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

I have an input that changes Excel sheet each time. Instead of manually changing the inputs, could I do something like the following:

```
n=3
for i=1
Data = xlsread('TestInput1.xlsx','B2:B9',"i");
Data
end
```

Since the last value in xlsread is a string, is this possible?

Comment: Use data conversion functions to obtain a string from a number: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the number `i` to a string.  The easiest option is `num2str`.  If you need more control of the output format you can usually get what you want with `sprintf`.  E.G.

```
n=3
for i=1:n
    Data = xlsread('TestInput1.xlsx',num2str(i),'B2:B9');
    Data
end
```

Comment: this is outputting the same matrix each time for the loop. I have the sheets names 1 2 and 3

Comment: It looks like the calling convention is `xlsread(file, sheet, range)` (order was wrong before).   See edit.